# Как вывести результат функции в html шаблон django/flask?

Tags: python, django, flask

этой мой первый вопрос на СтэкОверфлоу)
Я только начал изучать Python, и фреймворки django/flask. 
Делаю простенький сайт, который выводит json данные с других сайтов, погоду например.
Но с помощью js это не сделать, потому что запрещено CORS.
Для этого мне нужен flask.
Поэтому вопрос:
как вывести результат функции, в html шаблон.
Я гуглил, но безрезультатно.

```
def clock():
    response = requests.get('https://yandex.com/time/sync.json?geo=45')
    print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то итог должен быть примерно таким:

```
from flask import render_template
...
def func1():
    ...
    return(data1)

    ...

def funcN:
    ...
    return(dataN)

@app.route('/')
def clock():
    data1 = func1()
    ...
    dataN = funcN()
    ...
    return render_template('index.html', 
                           data1=data1, 
                           ..., 
                           dataN=dataN)
```

После чего, в основном шаблоне index.html импортировать нужные шаблоны html. Почитать как это делать можно [здесь](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/).

Одна из лучших книг для начинающих по Flask [здесь](https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/python/Flask%20Web%20Development_%20Developing%20Web%20Applications%20with%20Python%20%5BGrinberg%202014-05-18%5D.pdf).
Экспресс вариант [здесь](https://habr.com/post/346306/)

Comment: спасибо) я пробовал этот способ.Дело в том, что таких функций у меня несколько. Они парсят json с разных сайтов и выводят на одной странице.

Comment: тогда в чём задача? Объединить данные с разных сайтов и сделать общий вывод?

Comment: что вроде этого. Объединить данные с разных сайтов на одной странице. При этом аккуратно вставив их в шаблон.

Answer (score 0):

что вроде этого:
from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(**name**)

```
def clock():
    ...
    return render_template('clock.html', data=data)

def weather():
    ...
    return render_template('weather.html', data=data)

def date():
    ...
    return render_template('date.html', data=data)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return ('index.html', data=data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

три однотипные функции, мне надо вывести их на одной странице, в готовом шаблоне. Тоесть каждая функция выводится в определенной место шаблона.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div> функция </div>
</div>
```

Вопрос: как вывести эти функции, на начальную страницу, при этом не побив шаблон? Идеально это вставить функцию или ссылку на функцию в html код. Но как это сделать?